# How do I erase first letters of cells in data frame of a variable?

Tags: r

I am new in R programming, and i would like to "clean" data I found. This is the data frame and I would like to set up a ts() from the variable Month:

```
        Month     gas
        Jan 1973  79
        Feb 1973  79
        Mar 1973  77
        Apr 1973  73
        May 1973  77
```

I would like to have it like this:

```
   Month gas
   1973  79
   1973  79
   1973  77
   1973  73
   1973  77
```

Thanks for your precious help.

Comment: is your month column in chr format or date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assumed your `Month` is `chr` type, and `gas` integer. This will delete all the month name stand before the space.

```
Month <- c("Jan 1973","Feb 1973", "Mar 1973", "Apr 1973", "May 1973")
gas <- c(79,79,77,73,77)
df <- data.frame(Month, gas, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
# print(df)
df$Year <- unlist(strsplit(df$Month, split=" ", fixed=TRUE))[2]
df$Month <- NULL #delete old column
df <- data.frame(c(df[2], df[1])) # rearranged data frame
print(df)

# Year gas
# 1 1973  79
# 2 1973  79
# 3 1973  77
# 4 1973  73
# 5 1973  77
```

Comment: I take Month and gas from a large dataframe. Is there an easier way to associate a vector to a variable of a data.frame? because i can't see if it runs or not

Answer (score 1):

We can use `sub`

```
df1$Month <-  as.numeric(sub("^\\S+\\s+", '', df1$Month))
df1$Month
#[1] 1973 1973 1973 1973 1973
```

---

Or a slighly faster approach would be `substr` if the number of characters to extract are the same

```
 with(df1, as.numeric(substr(Month, nchar(Month)-3, nchar(Month))))
 #[1] 1973 1973 1973 1973 1973
```

---

If the "Month" is `yearmon` object (from `zoo`)

```
 library(lubridate)
 year(df1$Month)
 #[1] 1973 1973 1973 1973 1973
```

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(Month = c("Jan 1973", "Feb 1973", 
 "Mar 1973", 
"Apr 1973", "May 1973"), gas = c(79L, 79L, 77L, 73L, 
77L)), .Names = c("Month", 
"gas"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Comment: I do not have established a "df". What is it?

Comment: @matteomazzarano  It is the `data.frame` object

Comment: you need to check whether the Month variable is a factor .. if it is, then you need to use as.character before you can use sub or substr. (Or read in your data frame using as.is=TRUE or stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Comment: @lebatsnok  No need to convert to `as.character` with `sub` or `substr`

Comment: ok. you're right (`substr(factor(LETTERS),1,1)`) - but factors are still evil :)